# listview to display images in android

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a listview in android and i have a imageview in it

I am populating images into the list view i have a output like below::

[image]

**listview_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/flag"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

How can i make something like this below

[image]

Any ideas ! ... i am trying to achieve this in list view

Comment: check my answer below: `android:scaleType="fitXY"` put in XML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SET `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` attribute in xml or `imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true)` in Java.

ALSO

You can use **`android:scaleType="fitXY"`** in XML:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/flag"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

There are Many option for [`android:scaleType`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)

Answer (score 0):

add `scaleType` to ImageView

```
<ImageView
   android:id="@+id/flag"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
   android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
   android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
   android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```

Comment: That helps .... width i got  what i wanted ..... but the height ... it still a small .... row height size ...

Comment: Height you can fix with `android:layout_height="100dp"`

Answer (score 0):

Android have provided us many attributes to work with ImageView.

You can use adjustViewBounds and scaleType property in your case. Check example below:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/flag"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```